# CREATE Service Call

Tags: java, optimization, beginner

I'm a relatively new (~6 mos) developer, and I'm hoping for some feedback on my code style/structure. While I'm particularly interested in efficiency and maintainability, I'm open to feedback regarding anything that comes to mind from more experienced developers.

```
/**
 * Attempts to create new SavedSearch (eventual POST call) using current
 * search criteria. If searchName already exists in database, create does
 * NOT occur, and user is prompted.
 * 
 * @param event
 */
private void doCreateSavedSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    String THIS_METHOD_NAME = "doCreateSavedSearch";
    SavedSearch searchReturnedFromService = null;

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug(
                getClass(),
                THIS_METHOD_NAME,
                "Attempting to CREATE new SavedSearch | searchName="
                        + searchToSave.getSearchName());
    }
    try {
        searchReturnedFromService = savedSearchService.createSavedSearch(
                executionControlParameters, searchToSave);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME, "searchReturnedFromService=["
                    + searchReturnedFromService + "]");
        }

        if (searchReturnedFromService == null) { // indicates error from service
            ProcessingException e = new ProcessingException(
                    "RestClientBaseSavedSearchService", "SavedSearchService", null,
                    "searchReturnedFromService=" + searchReturnedFromService);
            throw e;
        }

        else if (null == searchReturnedFromService.getSearchName()) { // indicates name
                                                                        // already exists
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug(
                        getClass(),
                        THIS_METHOD_NAME,
                        "SEARCH NOT CREATED | searchName="
                                + searchToSave.getSearchName()
                                + " already exists in database (searchReturnedFromService.searchId="
                                + searchReturnedFromService.getSearchId() + ")");
            }
            searchNameExistsInDatabase = true;
            doUniqueNameViolationActions(searchReturnedFromService, event);
        }

        else {
            showMessage(
                    "search_results.operation.msg.confirmation.save_search.messgsuccess",
                    "INFO");

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME,
                        "SEARCH SUCCESSFULLY CREATED for searchName="
                                + searchReturnedFromService.getSearchName());
            }
            cleanUp();
        }
    }
    catch (ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion e) {
        showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
        logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
                + " | ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion - " + e.getMessage(), e);
        cleanUp();
    }
    catch (ProcessingException e) {
        showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
        logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
                + " | ProcessingException - " + e.getMessage(), e);
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a bit inconsistent with how you handle large argument lists. The large argument lists also make your code unreadable (or at least hard to read). I have trouble discerning the parts where your code does actual work and the parts where checks and logging happens.

```
private void doCreateSavedSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    String THIS_METHOD_NAME = "doCreateSavedSearch";
    SavedSearch searchReturnedFromService = null;

    /*logging*/ if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    /*logging*/     logger.debug(
    /*logging*/             getClass(),
    /*logging*/             THIS_METHOD_NAME,
    /*logging*/             "Attempting to CREATE new SavedSearch | searchName="
    /*logging*/                     + searchToSave.getSearchName());
    /*logging*/ }
    try {
        searchReturnedFromService = savedSearchService.createSavedSearch(
                executionControlParameters, searchToSave);

        /*logging*/ if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        /*logging*/     logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME, "searchReturnedFromService=["
        /*logging*/             + searchReturnedFromService + "]");
        /*logging*/ }

        if (searchReturnedFromService == null) { // indicates error from service
            ProcessingException e = new ProcessingException(
                    "RestClientBaseSavedSearchService", "SavedSearchService", null,
                    "searchReturnedFromService=" + searchReturnedFromService);
            throw e;
        }

        else if (null == searchReturnedFromService.getSearchName()) { // indicates name
                                                                        // already exists
            /*logging*/ if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            /*logging*/     logger.debug(
            /*logging*/             getClass(),
            /*logging*/             THIS_METHOD_NAME,
            /*logging*/             "SEARCH NOT CREATED | searchName="
            /*logging*/                     + searchToSave.getSearchName()
            /*logging*/                     + " already exists in database (searchReturnedFromService.searchId="
            /*logging*/                     + searchReturnedFromService.getSearchId() + ")");
            /*logging*/ }
            searchNameExistsInDatabase = true;
            doUniqueNameViolationActions(searchReturnedFromService, event);
        }

        else {
            showMessage(
                    "search_results.operation.msg.confirmation.save_search.messgsuccess",
                    "INFO");

            /*logging*/ if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            /*logging*/     logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME,
            /*logging*/             "SEARCH SUCCESSFULLY CREATED for searchName="
            /*logging*/                     + searchReturnedFromService.getSearchName());
            /*logging*/ }
            cleanUp();
        }
    }
    catch (ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion e) {
        showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
        logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
                + " | ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion - " + e.getMessage(), e);
        cleanUp();
    }
    catch (ProcessingException e) {
        showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
        logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
                + " | ProcessingException - " + e.getMessage(), e);
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Let's remove the logging bits, just so I can see what I'm dealing with.

```
private void doCreateSavedSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    String THIS_METHOD_NAME = "doCreateSavedSearch";
    SavedSearch searchReturnedFromService = null;

    try {
        searchReturnedFromService = savedSearchService.createSavedSearch(
                executionControlParameters, searchToSave);

        if (searchReturnedFromService == null) { // indicates error from service
            ProcessingException e = new ProcessingException(
                    "RestClientBaseSavedSearchService", "SavedSearchService", null,
                    "searchReturnedFromService=" + searchReturnedFromService);
            throw e;
        }

        else if (null == searchReturnedFromService.getSearchName()) { // indicates name
                                                                        // already exists
            searchNameExistsInDatabase = true;
            doUniqueNameViolationActions(searchReturnedFromService, event);
        }

        else {
            showMessage(
                    "search_results.operation.msg.confirmation.save_search.messgsuccess",
                    "INFO");

            cleanUp();
        }
    }
    catch (ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion e) {
        showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
        logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
                + " | ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion - " + e.getMessage(), e);
        cleanUp();
    }
    catch (ProcessingException e) {
        showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
        logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
                + " | ProcessingException - " + e.getMessage(), e);
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

We end up with... weirdly formatted code.

You use the following structure:

```
if (condition) {
    code
}

else if (condition) {
    code
}
```

Don't do that.

There's a couple schools of thought when it comes to braces `{}`...

```
//1
if (condition) {
   code
} else if (condition) {
   code
}

//2
if (condition) {
   code
} 
else if (condition) {
   code
}

//3
if (condition) 
{
   code
} 
else if (condition) 
{
   code
}
```

I suggest you pick one of these three. Right now, there's no way to see the if/elseif chain as connected, which makes the function hard to understand.

Moving on...

```
    logger.debug(
            getClass(),
            THIS_METHOD_NAME,
            "Attempting to CREATE new SavedSearch | searchName="
                    + searchToSave.getSearchName());
```

What happened here?

A single log call over 5 lines of code. It's drowning out your more important code!

Looking at all the log calls:

```
    logger.debug(
            getClass(),
            THIS_METHOD_NAME,
            "Attempting to CREATE new SavedSearch | searchName="
                    + searchToSave.getSearchName());

        logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME, "searchReturnedFromService=["
                + searchReturnedFromService + "]");

            logger.debug(
                    getClass(),
                    THIS_METHOD_NAME,
                    "SEARCH NOT CREATED | searchName="
                            + searchToSave.getSearchName()
                            + " already exists in database (searchReturnedFromService.searchId="
                            + searchReturnedFromService.getSearchId() + ")");

            logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME,
                    "SEARCH SUCCESSFULLY CREATED for searchName="
                            + searchReturnedFromService.getSearchName());

    logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
            + " | ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion - " + e.getMessage(), e);

    logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
            + " | ProcessingException - " + e.getMessage(), e);
```

You need to pass in `getClass()`, `THIS_METHOD_NAME`, and a message.
The first two parameters are always the same.

I'd try making them less pronounced:

```
    logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME,
                  "Attempting to CREATE new SavedSearch | searchName=" + searchToSave.getSearchName()
                 );
```

Perhaps even going as far as to do this:

```
    String debugMessage = "Attempting to CREATE new SavedSearch | searchName=" + searchToSave.getSearchName();
    logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME, debugMessage);
```

---

```
        ProcessingException e = new ProcessingException(
                "RestClientBaseSavedSearchService", "SavedSearchService", null,
                "searchReturnedFromService=" + searchReturnedFromService);
        throw e;
```

You don't use `e`. Consider using `throw new ProcessingException(...` instead.

---

```
        showMessage(
                "search_results.operation.msg.confirmation.save_search.messgsuccess",
                "INFO");
```

Magic string `"INFO"`, consider using an enum instead (see [java.util.logging.Level](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html)).

Magic string `"search_results.operation.msg.confirmation.save_search.messgsuccess"`, consider defining somewhere else (top of class). You WILL screw this up one day, and it will be really hard to spot it.

---

```
catch (ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion e) {
    showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
    logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
            + " | ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion - " + e.getMessage(), e);
    cleanUp();
}
catch (ProcessingException e) {
    showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
    logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
            + " | ProcessingException - " + e.getMessage(), e);
    cleanUp();
}
```

If you're gonna go with a specific yet generic exception handler, use multicatch:

```
catch (ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion | ProcessingException e) {
    showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
    logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
            + " | " + e.getClass().getName() + " - " + e.getMessage(), e);
    cleanUp();
}
```

---

```
    catch (ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion e) {
        showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
        logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
                + " | ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion - " + e.getMessage(), e);
        cleanUp();
    }
```

Typo; `ResourceAlreadyExistsExcepltion`.

---

Final result (not included: Enums for `showMessage`, Level for logging severities)

```
/**
 * Attempts to create new SavedSearch (eventual POST call) using current
 * search criteria. If searchName already exists in database, create does
 * NOT occur, and user is prompted.
 * 
 * @param event
 */
private void doCreateSavedSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    String THIS_METHOD_NAME = "doCreateSavedSearch";
    SavedSearch searchReturnedFromService = null;

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        String debugMessage = "Attempting to CREATE new SavedSearch | searchName=" 
                               + searchToSave.getSearchName();
        logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME, debugMessage);
    }
    try {
        searchReturnedFromService = savedSearchService.createSavedSearch(
                executionControlParameters, searchToSave);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            String debugMessage = "searchReturnedFromService=["
                                   + searchReturnedFromService 
                                   + "]";
            logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME, debugMessage);
        }

        if (searchReturnedFromService == null) { // indicates error from service
            throw new ProcessingException(
                    "RestClientBaseSavedSearchService", "SavedSearchService", null,
                    "searchReturnedFromService=" + searchReturnedFromService);
        } 
        else if (null == searchReturnedFromService.getSearchName()) { // indicates name already exists
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                String debugMessage = "SEARCH NOT CREATED | searchName="
                                        + searchToSave.getSearchName()
                                        + " already exists in database (searchReturnedFromService.searchId="
                                        + searchReturnedFromService.getSearchId() + ")";
                logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME, debugMessage);
            }
            searchNameExistsInDatabase = true;
            doUniqueNameViolationActions(searchReturnedFromService, event);
        } 
        else {
            showMessage(
                 "search_results.operation.msg.confirmation.save_search.messgsuccess",
                 "INFO");

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                String debugMessage = "SEARCH SUCCESSFULLY CREATED for searchName="
                                       + searchReturnedFromService.getSearchName();
                logger.debug(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME, debugMessage);
            }
            cleanUp();
        }
    }
    catch (ResourceAlreadyExistsException | ProcessingException e) {
        showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
        logger.error(getClass(), THIS_METHOD_NAME
                + " | " + e.getClass().getName() + " - " + e.getMessage(), e);
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Final result without logging:

```
/**
 * Attempts to create new SavedSearch (eventual POST call) using current
 * search criteria. If searchName already exists in database, create does
 * NOT occur, and user is prompted.
 * 
 * @param event
 */
private void doCreateSavedSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    String THIS_METHOD_NAME = "doCreateSavedSearch";
    SavedSearch searchReturnedFromService = null;

    try {
        searchReturnedFromService = savedSearchService.createSavedSearch(
                executionControlParameters, searchToSave);

        if (searchReturnedFromService == null) { // indicates error from service
            throw new ProcessingException(
                    "RestClientBaseSavedSearchService", "SavedSearchService", null,
                    "searchReturnedFromService=" + searchReturnedFromService);
        } 
        else if (null == searchReturnedFromService.getSearchName()) { // indicates name already exists
            searchNameExistsInDatabase = true;
            doUniqueNameViolationActions(searchReturnedFromService, event);
        } 
        else {
            showMessage(
                 "search_results.operation.msg.confirmation.save_search.messgsuccess",
                 "INFO");

            cleanUp();
        }
    }
    catch (ResourceAlreadyExistsException | ProcessingException e) {
        showMessage("error.error.message.default", "ERROR");
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! It'll take a while to process/practice with all of the feedback, but a quick question in the meantime: I've been using Eclipse's autoformat feature - is there a way to personalize it to make the result more readable?

Comment: @JeffLevine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392744/how-do-i-configure-autoformatting-in-eclipse